Properties of weak equivalences of Lie Groupoids
I've been studying Moerdijk and Mrčun's book "Introduction to Foliations and Lie Groupoids" and I am having difficulties with Prop. 5.12.
Recall that a weak equivalence of Lie Groupoids is a morphism $\varphi:\mathcal{G} \to \mathcal{H}$ that is fully faithful and essentially surjective; in which the first condition is that the following diagram is a pullback of manifolds
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{G}_{1} @>{\varphi}>> \mathcal{H}_{1}\\
@V{(s,t)}VV @V{(s,t)}VV\\
\mathcal{G}_{0} \times \mathcal{G}_{0} @>{\varphi \times \varphi}>> \mathcal{H}_{0} \times \mathcal{H}_{0};
\end{CD}
and the second condition means that the map $t \circ \pi_{1}: \mathcal{H}_{1} {}^{s}\times^{\varphi}_{\mathcal{H}_{0}} \mathcal{G}_{0} \to \mathcal{H}_{0}$ is a surjective submersion.
There are two propositions on with I need help. Let $\mathcal{G}, \mathcal{H}, \mathcal{K}$ be Lie groupoids.
First: If $\varphi, \psi:\mathcal{G} \to \mathcal{H}$ be two morphisms of Lie groupoids, and $T:\varphi \implies \psi$ is a natural transformation, $\varphi$ is a weak equivalence iff $\psi$ is a weak equivalence.
For this one, I considered trying to use the natural transformation morphisms to 'transform' the relevant diagrams and morphisms of the weak equivalence to the other morphism, but this isn't working.
Second: If $\varphi: \mathcal{G} \to \mathcal{H}$, and $\psi:\mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{K}$ are weak equivalences, then the composition is also a weak equivalence.
For this one, I know that the diagram that needs to be a pullback is the composition of diagram pullbacks, so it is one. The essential surjectivity is being the hard one. I tried to describe $t \circ \pi_{1} : \mathcal{K}_{1} \times_{\mathcal{K}_{0}} \mathcal{G}_{0} \to \mathcal{K}_{0}$ in term of the other analogous maps, sort of like a composition, but I haven't had success.
Any help is appreciated.
